# how to add fading effect this javascript random image

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(function(){ 
        var change = Array("forimg1","img1");
        var r = change[Math.floor(Math.random() * change.length)];
        if(r == "forimg1"){
            document.getElementById("imagetitle").innerHTML = "Makati Cafe";
        }
        if(r == "img1"){

            document.getElementById("imagetitle").innerHTML = "The Fort Steak House";
        }
        $("#image_change").attr("src","assets/images/eat/"+r+".jpg");

    },2000);
</script>
```

Comment: add html code also ..

Comment: Given the "jQuery" tag, `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`? Or is that too obvious?

Comment: that's why I'm asking on how to put that .fadeOut and .fadeIn() in this code. because I'm newbie in Jquery and Javascript

Comment: that's why I'm asking on how to put that .fadeOut and .fadeIn() in this code. because I'm newbie in Jquery and Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the image titles together with the image URLs, by using an array of objects like:

```
var images = [
  {title: "Makati Cafe", file: "img1"},
  {title: "The Fort Steak House", file: "img2"},
  // etc.
]
```

That way you don't need the if/else structure to figure out what title to display, you can just pick up both title and filename from the current object with `images[current].title` and `images[current].file`.

You also don't really need `setInterval()`, because if you use the jQuery [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) functions they can control the timing for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = [
    {title: "Makati Cafe", file: "g/200/250"},
    {title: "The Fort Steak House", file: "200/250"},
    {title: "Whatever", file: "200/350"}
    // etc.
  ];
  var $container = $("#container"); // keep references to the container div
  var $img = $("#image_change");    // and img and title elements rather than
  var $title = $("#image_title");   // looking them up every time we fade
  
  function showNext() {
    var current = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    // fade out container, then
    $container.delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
      // update img src and title text
      $img.attr("src", "http://placekitten.com/" + images[current].file);
      $title.text(images[current].title);
      // fade container in again and then call the showNext() function again
      $container.fadeIn(500, showNext);
    });
  }
  showNext();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p id="image_title"></p>
  <img id="image_change">
</div>
```

You didn't show your HTML in the question, so I've just assumed there will be a container div with an img and title element inside it, and then I've faded that container. Obviously you can modify the code to suit your actual HTML structure.

(Don't worry about the weird file names in the code above, they're just stock images for demo purposes.)